# Custom search terms SP2007

Tags: 2007, search

I have a set of documents/pages etc which has a category. I would like to make a custom search that will have terms like:

(TextBox)Title
(CheckBox)Category1
(CheckBox)Category2
(CheckBox)Category3

But I have no idea how to start with that.

Could you tell me how to start working on that?